# Fetch table row data as per the selected checkbox

Tags: javascript, php, html, material-design, material-design-lite

I am using Material Design Lite to create a table and I am inserting rows dynamically using php. 
The material design lite has provided checkboxes for each row. Now, I want to use the selected row's data on a button click. Does anyone have any idea how to do that?

Here is the code :

```
<table class="mdl-data-table mdl-js-data-table mdl-data-table--selectable mdl-shadow--2dp" id="sanctionedTable">
<thead>
<tr>
  <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Name</th>
  <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Registration No.</th>
  <th class="mdl-data-table__cell--non-numeric">Amount</th>
</tr>
</thead>
<tbody>
<?php 
$temp = "";
  while($row = mysqli_fetch_assoc($result))
  {
    $temp="<tr><td>".$row["name"]."</td><td>".$row["regno"]."</td><td>".$row["amount"]."</td></tr>";
    echo $temp;
  }
?>
</tbody>
</table>
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use something like this using jquery:

```
$('tr').click(function(){

alert("Name:"+$(this).children('td:nth-child(1)').html()+",Registration nio:"+$(this).children('td:nth-child(2)').html()+",Amount:"+$(this).children('td:nth-child(3)').html());
});
```

This fetches the information in each row.